# Get a remote Windows Computer to perform a Login C#

Tags: c#, networking

I'am managing a Lab with around 15 Computers. I wrote a little program to start all of the from one computer and to shut all of them down from a remote computer... So far so good. But it would be really nice to get all computers to do a login (credentials given from the app). There are on all 15 Computers the same user accounts (exp1/exp2). Sometimes all computers are needed logged in by exp1 and sometimes as exp2. Are there any Ideas how I can do this? Any hints on what to search? I'm googling now for a long time. 
Please help.

Cheers
Eydrian

Comment: Maybe there's a way to automatically update the registry settings that allow for automatic login? Like at some stage just prior to the login screen actually appearing, you could prefill the registry values with the desired username, password, and flip the flag to enable automatic login?

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter said you can set the autolongin and reboot the machines or you can get some kind of remote control software like netop.  There is no way built into windows to login remotely to the gui primary windows station as it would be a massive security risk.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the version of Windows. If it's XP you might be able to do it with a GINA replacement. Some information can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx

In Vista GINAs was replaced with Credential Providers but I think they are more limited.

Comment: Yep, XP, thx for all the answers. I tried with P-Invoke and advapi32... But didn't get any useful results. I'll try with GINA or with the autologin and restart, but there's going to be lot of restarts this way!
thx