# Can you force a "local" GUI login to a remote computer on Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-10, remote-access, psexec

I am using PSExec logged into an administrative privileged account on Computer A, to run a batch file on Computer B. I am successfully completing this batch file with elevated privilege on Computer B.

I am also aware PSExec can use the "-i" switch to interact with the desktop, which, when Computer B has someone logged in and sitting at the desktop, works fine.

**My question is if Windows 10 or any related Microsoft toolkit gives you the ability to, from Computer A, force a "local desktop login" from Computer B. So that when the command is executed from Computer A, Computer B is now logged in, sitting at the desktop.**

***(if you cannot do this, is there a way to know if a specific user is logged in with an active "gui desktop session" active, i.e. the screen isn't locked)***

The reason I want to do this, is because I want to stop a GUI application on Computer B. Update the application (touch the file), and then relaunch the application. But obviously since this application is a GUI application, if Computer B wasn't logged in with an active session, I don't think this is entirely desirable.

I don't want to use any sketchy 3rd party application/API. I am proficient in C++/C#/other coding languages, so if this is not possible by "batch" but can be accomplished in code, that's fine to me.

I found this topic in the link below which somewhat relates, but I am not using C#, and this thread is now 11 years old and using Windows XP. The comment below seems to indicate this wasn't possible in 2010 on XP.

[Get a remote Windows Computer to perform a Login C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560628/get-a-remote-windows-computer-to-perform-a-login-c-sharp), the comment here:  "There is no way built into windows to login remotely to the gui primary windows station as it would be a massive security risk."

- Both Computers are the same version of Windows 10
- I have administrative access to both computers
- I have network access between the computers

Comment: Edit: Found this can help me see if someone is actively logged into remote PC, in the event it's not possible to "force" the local PC to login, remotely.
query user /server:computername

Comment: Can you not do it via a group policy or a deployment tool as opposed to what you're proposing?  Forcing a login on another machine via remote scripting or otherwise sounds a bit insecure to me....

Comment: Yeah it sounds insecure to me as well, based on some light research. I figured it might not be realistic, but thought there might be some application for it, so maybe there was a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the usage of psexec and batch, I don't think what you want can be accomplished without the use of external tools, unless you want to do it manually with something like RDP.

However, you can use powershell to PSRemote into the machine with `Enter-PSSession` then run a `quser` to see if someone is logged in. Then, depending on the situation, you can run `Get-Process` to get the PID of the app in question, `Stop-Process` to kill it, and various PowerShell commands to play with the file. Then, when all is said and done, run a `Start-Process` to restart the app, then `Exit-PSSession` to leave.

I highly recommend using psexec and batch as a last resort.

Comment: Yeah, could possibly modify this (swap out enabling remote registry to your quser/get-process/stop-process etc): https://www.alkanesolutions.co.uk/2021/08/04/enable-windows-remote-management-winrm-on-remote-devices/